# MS Access 2016 VBA Code Reuse in Buttons

Tags: ms-access, vba, code-reuse

I have an Access database frontend that houses 16 different forms. All of them have three buttons in common namely **Show All**, **Clear** and **Refresh**, that perform that exact same function using their respective subforms. For instance, for viewing data from a table named **tbl_Students** the 'On Click' event of these buttons on the **Students Form** have the following code:

```
Option Explicit
'Show all records button
Private Sub cmdShowAll_Click()
    Dim task As String
    task = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Students"
    Me.frm_Students_subform.Form.RecordSource = task
    Me.frm_Students_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub

'Clear displayed records button
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    Dim task As String
    task = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Students WHERE (StudentID) is null"
    Me.frm_Students_subform.Form.RecordSource = task
    Me.frm_Students_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub

'Refresh records button
Private Sub cmdRefresh_Click()
    Me.frm_Students_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Currently, I'm using the exact same code, but with different respective subform names, in all my 16 forms. Is there a better, more efficient way to do it, with code reuse? Thanks.

Comment: task string also varies

Comment: Please be explicit in what you want to reuse. Reusing a refresh button with one line of code seems kind of pointless. Your other functions seem to vary. Usually, you can reuse by creating a class and setting the form and buttons as properties using `WithEvents`, but you're not clear in your question.

Comment: Sorry if I was vague. I actually have many identical buttons on all my forms, having the exact same code, with the exception that only the subform names are different. Can I select the subform in each of my respective form subroutines, using lesser amount of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating **one** generalized subroutine in a standard module that all 16 forms call passing needed parameters. Specifically use [CurrentProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/currentproject-object-access) and [Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-controls-property-access) to reference objects dynamically by string.

**Module** *save in a named standard module (not behind any form)*

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcessForms(task As String, mainform As String, subform As String)
On Error GoTo ErrHandle

    CurrentProject.AllForms(mainform).Controls(subform).Form.RecordSource = task
    CurrentProject.AllForms(mainform).Controls(subform).Requery
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

**Example Form** *single line calls*

```
Option Explicit
'Show all records button

Private Sub cmdShowAll_Click()
    Call ProcessForms("SELECT * FROM tbl_Students", _
                      "frm_students", "frm_Students_subform")
End Sub

'Clear displayed records button
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    Call ProcessForms("SELECT * FROM tbl_Students WHERE (StudentID) IS NULL", _
                      "frm_students", "frm_Students_subform")
End Sub

'Refresh records button
Private Sub cmdRefresh_Click()
    ' Re-assigns same recordsource in line with others
    Call ProcessForms(Me.Controls("frm_Students_subform").Form.RecordSource, _
                      "frm_students", "frm_Students_subform")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. On a side note, should I add error handling code to these subroutines, or leave them as they are, since they're very basic?